# How should I write TestNG test cases so that they can be run one after another (sequentially)?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have project with this structure of TestNG classes:
[image]

I want to create a .xml file (and I'll create batch file to run it from Jenkins in the future) to be able to run each test class sequentially. How should I write each test?

Here's example of my script:

```
package CRM;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class logowanie {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 


@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("***");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("***");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("_submit")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
  }

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest() {

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://crm.serwis-grupowy-vgp.pl/login");
    }

@AfterMethod
public void afterTest() throws InterruptedException {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/logout']")).click();
driver.quit();

     }}
```

Here's .xml script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_mcall_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_HTG_czerw_sierp_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_rbp_tab_wykresy_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_cnptool_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_zakup_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_materialy_info_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_raporty_od_0110_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_HTG_wrze_gru_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_materialy_z_wydarzen_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_bonus_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_bonus_tabele_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_akcesoria_podstrony_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_nora_podstrony_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_moj_kalendarz_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_akcesoria_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_nora_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_autopart_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_wydarzenia_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_pisma_okolne_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_raporty_do_3009_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_baza_marketingowa_MI"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.logowanie_MartynaDealer"/>
  <class name="PP_MartynaDealer.podstrona_uzytkownicy_MI"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

At the moment browser windows are opened one per each test that is executed, all at once and after the last browser window is opened, test starts in first window and they go sequentially.
Should I write tests in a different way, so that I can run them sequentially?

Comment: i do not understand your question. you already have preserve-order in your suite, so all the tests will be run in the order mentioned in the suite...

Comment: the problem is that selenium opens at the same time as many browser windows as tests and I want it to open one window-perform test-close window and repeat that action for every test included in the suite

Comment: You shouldn't really depend on the order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349496/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason why you see a lot of browser windows popup is due to this below line

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

This line at the class level causes the browsers to be spun off much before the tests are even beginning to execute. You might want to move this line (the instantiation part and not the declaration part) into a setup method.

Comment: I don't really understand where should I move this line, sorry. When I move it to beforeMethod, I'm getting errors in @Test part - driver cannot be resolved. It shows that all commands are unknown if there isn't 'WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();' before them

Answer (score 0):

you could add preserve-order="true", so in your xml, it will be like :

```
<test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
```

another way to do this is to add

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testThatWillBeExecutedBeforeThis" })
```

to each of your test cases.